# Problem creating new Dataframe that depends on another Dataframe in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new Dataframe based on this Dataframe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxx2l.png)

And with this code, I am trying to create a new Dataframe that should give me a new row X times per second (here X=1/15), so for the first 5 seconds I should get 5/(1/15)=75 rows that are the same in 'Risque' column

```
 while i< 30:
    if (CC78.iloc[i]['Articulation']=="Cou"):
        if (CC78.iloc[i]['Duree'] < x):
            Cou2 = Cou2.append(pd.Series([CC78.iloc[i+j]['Risque']]), ignore_index=True)
            Frame2 = Frame2.append(pd.Series(i+j), ignore_index=True)   
        else: 
            res=(CC78.iloc[i]['Duree'] / x) + 1
            k=0
            while k <= int(res):                      
                Cou2 = Cou2.append(pd.Series([CC78.iloc[i+j]['Risque']]), ignore_index=True)
                Frame2 = Frame2.append(pd.Series(i+j), ignore_index=True)
                k=k+1
                j=j+1
    i=i+1
```

But the result I am getting is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXxuJ.png)

And sometimes I have indexing problem  such as :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygZqt.png)

I don't really understand why the resulting Dataframe is the same as the base Dataframe.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit :
I found the problem, instead of CC78.iloc[i+j], I should have used CC78.iloc[i],
because "i" has nothing to do with my new Dataframe, it's just used for the base one.